# Real Analysis - Show that $A \cap B$ = {sup A} if sup A = inf B and sup A $\in$ $A \cap B$

Tags: real-analysis

If the subset A is bounded above and B is bounded below, and sup A = inf B, sup A $\in$ $A\cap B$. Prove that $A\cap B$ = {sup A}.

I've tried to solve this and I hope you could check it for correctness. I've said, suppose any element $x \in A \cap B$. Then $x \in A \land x \in B$.

Since $x \in A$, $x \leq$ sup A by the definition of sup A. Since sup A = inf B, $x \leq$ inf B. (i)

Also, $x \in B$, so $x \geq$ inf B by the definition of inf B. (ii)

By (i) and (ii), $x$ = inf B = sup A for any random x $\in A \cap B$. Therefore, $A \cap B$ = {sup A}.

Is this proof correct? I'm not quite sure about the last line. I know that usually, set equality is proven by showing that both sets are subsets of each other, but I thought by this proof, I had already shown equality. Is this correct?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Everything you wrote is correct. You're also right in saying that to prove set equality, you need to show that they're both included in one another. What you've proven is $A \cap B \subset \{ \sup A \}$; you still need to prove $\{ \sup A \} \subset A \cap B$ (but that's obvious since you're given $\sup A \in A \cap B$).

Answer (score 0):

You already have $\{\sup A\} \subset A \cap B$ from the hypotheses, so all that's needed is showing $A \cap B \subset \{\sup A \}$, which you have done.